# what am I missing? node.js stripe connect integration

Tags: angularjs, node.js, oauth, passport.js, stripe-payments

have been banging my head trying to get this stripe connect integration with standalone accounts complete.

> Getting started
>   Register your platform. (You only need to do this once.)
>   Create or connect to accounts for your users, for example sellers or service providers.

So I have registered my platform, got my API keys. I have added a 'Connect to stripe' button on my site.

Which links to the login or register page for users [image]

EDIT: 
I have am now trying to set up the passport-stripe strategy, however I don't really understand what I am trying to achieve.

Stripe provides a link to this documentation [github gist](https://gist.github.com/padolsey/7109113) , however recommends that you don't use it (?!) and instead use oauth documentation.

so, bearing in mind all my other authentication is set up using passport, I have used https://github.com/passport/passport-stripe#usage

under /server/config/strategies/ I added a file for stripe.js

```
'use strict';
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var path = require('path');
var passport = require('passport'),
  StripeStrategy = require('passport-stripe').Strategy,
  User = require('mongoose').model('User'),
  errorHandler = require(path.resolve('./modules/core/server/controllers/errors.server.controller'));

module.exports = function(config) {
  passport.use(new StripeStrategy({
    clientID: '',
    clientSecret: '',
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/stripe/callback"
  }, function(accessToken, refreshToken, stripe_properties, done) {
//    User.findOrCreate({
//      stripeId: stripe_properties.stripe_user_id
//    }, function(err, user) {
//      return done(err, user);
//    });
      exports.update = function (req, res) {
  var user = req.model;

  //For security purposes only merge these parameters
  user.firstName = req.body.firstName;
  user.lastName = req.body.lastName;
  user.displayName = user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
  user.roles = req.body.roles;
  user.stripeId = stripe_properties.stripe_user_id;       

  user.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    }

    res.json(user);
  });
};
  }));
};
```

and to my auth.server.routes.js I added:

```
app.get('/api/auth/stripe',
  passport.authenticate('stripe', { scope: 'read_write' }));

app.get('/api/auth/stripe/callback',
  passport.authenticate('stripe', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

**EDIT: '/api/auth/stripe' is pointing to https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=&scope=read_write , the login/register form in the image. but then on trying to redirect to  '/api/auth/stripe/callback' it just gives me 'server error'**

I have no idea if I am even heading in the right direction. I don't get how it all ties together. I have tried asking stripe support for some direction however the guy told me he doesn't know how to use passport.

**Any direction on this would be greatly appreciated**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Off topic but you might want to remove your actual API keys as well as the app secret. A malicious user can do lots of harm with them...

Comment: thanks, I missed one of them! >.<

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using Passport, you should use the [`passport-stripe`](https://github.com/passport/passport-stripe) module.

You can find usage instructions here: https://github.com/passport/passport-stripe#usage